# How do you render objects from json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I need to render some images from some json that I am being given. The code looks like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $.get(
    "url"
    data => {

    });

  }
  render() {
    return React.createElement("div", null, "hello");
  }}


ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.body);
```

"url" is the json that I have passed in (but I do not want to make it public). It looks similar to this:

```
{
    "total_count": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": ""
        },
        "next": {
            "href": ""
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "showorks": [{
            "id": "",
            "slug": "",
            "created_at": "",
            "updated_at": "",
            "title": "",
            "category": "",
            "medium": ",
            "date": "",
            "dimensions": {
                "in": {
                    "text": "",
                    "height": 70.9,
                    "width": 70.9,
                    "depth": null,
                    "diameter": null
                },
                "cm": {
                    "text": "180.1 × 180.1 cm",
                    "height": 180.1,
                    "width": 180.1,
                    "depth": null,
                    "diameter": null
                }
            },
            "published": true,
            "website": "",
            "signature": "",
            "series": null,
            "prov": "",
            "lit": "",
            "hist": "",
            "isst": "",
            "additional_information": "",
            "image_rights": "",
            "blurb": "",
            "unique": false,
            "maker": null,
            "icon": ,
            "inquire": false,
            "acquire": false,
            "share": true,
            "message": null,
            "sell":,
            "image_versions": ,
            "_links": {
                "thumbnail": {
                    "href": ""
                },
                "image": {
                    "href": "",
                    "templated": true
                },
                "partner": {
                    "href": ""
                },
                "self": {
                    "href": ""
                },
                "link": {
                    "href": ""
                },
                "genes": {
                    "href": ""
                },
                "rar": {
                    "href": ""
                },
                "cim": {
                    "href": ""
                },
                "coll": {
                    "href": ""
                }
            },
            "_embedded": {
                "editions": []
            }
        }, {
            "id": "",
```

I need the thumbnail for each id but I'm not sure how to iterate through the json to pull out each thumbnail in react/javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I totally recommend you to use JSX syntax to use React better. To do that, you will need a few Javascript Array helper function and some methods.

**As you can see below:**

```
class App extends React.Component
{
  componentDidMount()
  {
    // We could imagine the incoming JSON data
    // const exampleJson =
    // {
    //  elements:
    //  [
    //    { href: 'example1', text: 'link value', style: { height: '10px' } },
    //  ],
    // };

    // This fetch API will help you to get JSON from URL like JQuery $.get
    const exampleJson = fetch('http://example.com/links.json')
      .then(function(response)
      {
        return response.json(); // get the values of JSON as string type
      })
      .then(function(myJson)
      {
        return JSON.stringify(myJson); // convert the JSON data to javascript object
      });

    this.setState(exampleJson); // it's like this.setState({ elements: [array values] });

    console.log(exampleJson); // to do debug of your JSON data
  }

  render()
  {
   // we getting the elements array from state object
   // with object spread operator
   const { elements } = this.state;

   // get values all of your json array
   // loop values to do React element
   // return all new values to use loopAndSaveElements variable
   const loopAndSaveElements = elements
     .map(({ text, ...otherProps}) => React.createElement('a', otherItems, text));

   // send return div of React as loopAndSaveElements as array children
   return React.createElement("div", null, loopAndSaveElements);
  }
}
```

By the way, i didn't run the snippet of example. But i hope it give you an information.

**ES6+ Sources:**

- [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
- [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [JSX syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-build.html#do-i-need-to-use-jsx-with-react)
- [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: It's bad practice to `map()` `elements` on every render.. Better to save the results(`loopAndSaveElements`) to state instead of `elements` in the `componentDidMount`

Comment: My json is actually a url that's being passed in to the $.get (sorry should have mentioned that). It's the "json" in $.get(
    "json"
    data => {

    });

So where would that go in your code?

Comment: @stillearning I've gave the fetch details now. You can check it.

Comment: @SethMcClaine he is in so early stage in React. It's better to use map in render for now. It won't need to recalculate when data change. It might going to be hard in this step to get changes of the new data.

Comment: @Mustafa when I try the code, I'm not seeing the json rendering :/

Comment: By the way, it's just snippet/logic. You should change according to your JSON logic. What kind of did you get error? Also you can use console.log(exampleJson); in componentDidMount to see your data what happened exactly.

Comment: @Mustafa I added the console.log to your code. Is this the place to add it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197106/discussion-between-mustafa-and-stillearning).

Comment: @Mustafa, it will recalc on every redraw. so if state changes its recalculating the map data even if the data hasn't changed.